# DFA - unsigned int with digits in non-decreasing order

Tags: finite-automata

I was hoping someone could help me in understanding how to achieve a DFA here. The question is how I would create a DFA that accepts unsigned decimal integers whose digits are in non-decreasing order, such as 1234, 1589? The numbers can't start with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you'd determine yourself whether a number's digits are non-decreasing: you'd look at each digit in turn and remember each digit just long enough to check that the next digit is at least as big. You'll be happy as long as it always is at least as big, and sad if you find one that's smaller.<sup>1</sup>
So do the same with a DFA, using the currrent state to encode anything you need to remember.

---

<sup>1. OK, maybe you're not *that* emotionally invested in this problem...</sup>

Comment: So i tried to do that first with a NFA, but it became really big and im not sure if it was the right course of action. Will converting the NFA to DFA make it shorter?

Comment: You don't need an NFA. The natural implementation of "The state is the last digit you saw, plus maybe a start state and a sink state" is deterministic. You'll need about eleven states ("about" because I've not drawn out the automaton, so I might have made a small mistake).

Comment: I'd say 12 states if you count one state before any digit was entered, if you don't accept an empty input string, and one state for input that violated the rules so far. If you allow an empty input, then it's eleven states.

Comment: @gnasher729 The number can't begin with zeros and, hence, can't include any zeros, which saves a state. If the empty string is accepted, the initial state can be the "I just read a 1" state.